# How to deploy to GlassFish4 instance in Docker through IntelliJ?

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, windows-10, ioexception, glassfish-4

I'm currently trying to use IntelliJ to deploy to a local GlassFish instance running in Docker on my Windows 10 box.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-glassfish-server.html) on deployment, using the remote server setup.

However, when calling the run command, I get the following error from IntelliJ:

> Artifact my-project:war: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: File not found : /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/my-domain/config/C:[PATH_TO_MY_TARGET_DIR]\my-project.war

It seems like it's trying to pass too much of the path when uploading.

Interestingly, I tried this same setup (different IP addy) deploying to a GlassFish instance running in Docker in a local Ubuntu VM, and it has no problem.

Anyone gone down this road?

Comment: I initially tried using the local server configuration, but it wants to call some `asadmin` commands it doesn't have access to due to being hosted in the container, which led me to the remote setup.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem and contacted JetBrains.

It seems to be a bug in IntelliJ wich will be hopefully fixed quite soon. Here is the link for reference https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180292.